# hibernate ImprovedNamingStrategy overrides Table name in entity

Tags: hibernate

I am using org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy, But for a table I have specified the table name explicitly

```
@Table(name="EventLog",schema = "eventlogs")
```

But hibernate seems to be looking for event_log. Shouldn't explicit naming override the one provided by ImprovedNamingStrategy

Comment: Annotations should have a priority over naming strategy. Are you using [@org.hibernate.annotations.Table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Table.html) or [@javax.persistence.Table](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)? Maybe try the other one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the behavior of the org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy , which will convert the mixed case names to the embedded underscores name . http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html . So if you explicitly use the name "EventLog" , it will convert to the "event_log" .

If you simply want to use the name explicitly  specified in the `@Table` , you should use the org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy . By default it is used when you instantiate your org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  object

Comment: I thing hibernate 4+ changed the DefaultNamingStrategy in order that it ignores the annotated table name now also. Configuring the use of EJB3NamingStrategy should still recognise the annotated names. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to use the ImprovedNamingStrategy for all tables except those which specify a name explicitly you can use the subclass below. The **columnName** and **tableName** methods are the ones called when a name is explicitly specified, this subclass leaves the specified names unmolested.

I think it's odd that this is not the default behaviour.

```
public class RespectfulImprovedNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy
{
    @Override
    public String columnName(String columnName)
    {
        return columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName)
    {
        return tableName;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you going to apply to just 1 table ? And how it is different then built-in DefaultNamingStrategy ?

Comment: When a 'name' parameter is not specified in the `@Table` annotation, DefaultNamingStrategy assumes that the table name is the unqualified class name; i.e. the table name generated for class x.x.AccountStatus would be 'AccountStatus'.
If you specify a name parameter in the `@Table` attribute it will use whatever that is instead.
The table names generated by ImprovedNamingStrategy favour underscores instead of camel case i.e. 'account_status'
ImprovedNamingStrategy ignores the 'name' parameter in the `@Table` annotation, my suggestion just makes it respect the name parameter when it is present.

Comment: As far as I know you can't/wouldn't apply it for just one table. The naming strategy applies to a session.

Comment: You saved my day! Searched many places but never explained this concept.

Answer (score 3):

for hibernate 4 with spring

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

for hibernate5 with spring

```
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitely advise hibernate to use the old EJB3NamingStrategy which recognises the annotated table names by defining following property (depending using spring V4+ or not):

Spring:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

No spring (only hibernate):

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```