# Spring jpa modifies column names

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm using spring-jpa and I give column names to entities like;

```
@Column(name="UserDetail")
```

But it looks for user_detail. How can I give custom column names?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050538/hibernate-improvednamingstrategy-overrides-table-name-in-entity

Comment: Thank you. It seems same question but I don't know how to implement the answer on Spring programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

To change the naming strategy used by hibernate :

If you have a persistence.xml file, then change

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
```