# Envers queries use wrong column names for _MOD columns

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers with the `@Audited( withModifiedFlag=true )` and I have a problem where the SQL generated for queries has different column names than the one generated by the `HBM2DDL` tool for the `_MOD` columns

The issue might have something to do with the fact that I am overriding the Hibernate naming strategy as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594354/11758992). But trying to debug this, I have had no luck in verifying this theory - the naming strategy does not seem to hit any breakpoints.

The entity looks like this (with irrelevant properties omitted):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class FileEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;
}
```

The generated `_AUD` table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE file_AUD (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    REV int4 NOT NULL,
    REVTYPE int2,
    REVEND int4,
    file_name varchar(255),
    fileName_MOD boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, REV)
);
```

I can see the difference between the `file_name` and `fileName_MOD` columns, but that seems to be expected, as described [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10398)

When making a change to the entity or when using the `AuditReaderFactory` for a query, the following SQL error is shown:

```
ERROR: column fileentity0_.file_name_mod does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "fileentity0_.filename_mod".
```

I am using PostgreSQL and Hibernate `5.2.13.Final`
I understand there is a workaround with using the `modifiedColumnName` on each property, but the example above is just one of many entities I am trying to audit, so I am looking for other solutions.

EDIT:

Digging a bit deeper into the NamingStrategy, it seems the code was not actually using the custom one I had added. It seems the Hibernate `naming_strategy` property was split into `implicit_naming_strategy` and `physical_naming_strategy` and this seems to have went unnoticed as the version of Hibernate in the project was updated.
Instead, these properties are provided by Spring JPA by default as follows:

```
hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy:org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy:org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Since they do the job (outside of this Envers issue), I will not be using the custom one.

An example of a query I use:

```java
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
        .forRevisionsOfEntity(FileEntity.class, false, true)
        .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
        .setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset())
        .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
```

Comment: hi @andkov, could you update your post and include your naming strategy implementation code and an example of how you're either issuing a query or updating the entity and hitting this error?  I'd like to try to reproduce it if I could but I'd need those details to check it.

Comment: Thanks @Naros, I've edited the post, let me know if I am still missing something. Meanwhile, I have gone with the manual renaming of the SQL columns to take the form of `file_name_mod` instead of `fileName_MOD`. Not ideal, but seems to work for now

Comment: The best solution is to extend the spring-boot implementations and check to see if the identifier ends with `_MOD` and if so, simply have it return the same identifier without changing it.  You then just need to configure spring-boot to use your custom naming strategy and everything would work without having to rename the columns.

Comment: I agree this is the best solution, if you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution is to extend the `spring-boot` implementations and check whether the identifeir ends with the `_MOD` suffix and if so, have it return the same identifier without changing it.  Then configure `spring-boot` to use the custom naming strategy and things should work without having to rename columns.